# login issue in https in django 1.6

Tags: django, https

In django 1.6 , when we tried to login using django login then after successful login , user is redirected to same login page. only change is , we change the http protocol to https.

Comment: In settings.py file , added below line

os.environ['HTTPS'] = 'on'

now issue is resolved. Users are able to login in https

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py file ,
added below line os.environ['HTTPS'] = 'on';
now issue is resolved. Users are able to login in https